# Удаление текста в div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер, есть разметка:

```
<div class="short-genre">
    <a href="/">Вася</a>,
    <a href="/">Дима</a>,
    <a href="/">Лена</a>,
    <a href="/">Витя</a>
</div>
```

На выходе имеем:

```
Вася, Дима, Лена, Витя
```

Как с помощью js/jquery удалить первую ссылку (Вася) вместе с запятой и пробелом, что бы осталось только

```
Дима, Лена, Витя
```

?

Внимание, нужно удалить Васю, если его нет в списке то ничего не удалять.
Наверное, проще использовать регулярку, которая

найдет `<a href="/vasya">Вася</a>,` и заменит на ничего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery поддерживает селектор `:contains` - позволяющий выбирать элемент содержащий указанный текст. Так как запятая не внутри ссылку удаляем ее отдельно.

```js
$(function() {
  var toremove = $('.short-genre a:contains("Вася")');
  if (toremove.length > 0) {
    var next = toremove[0].nextSibling;
    if (next && next.textContent.indexOf(',') != -1) next.remove();
  }
  toremove.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="short-genre">
  <a href="/">Вася</a>,
  <a href="/">Дима</a>,
  <a href="/">Лена</a>,
  <a href="/">Витя</a>
</div>
```

Регулярными выражениями не советуют пользоваться для разбора не регулярных грамматик, но для простых случаев их можно применить примерно так:

```js
var toremove = document.querySelector('.short-genre');
if (toremove) {
  toremove.innerHTML = toremove.innerHTML.replace(/<a.*?Вася<\/a>,?/,'');
}
```

```html
<div class="short-genre">
  <a href="/">Вася</a>,
  <a href="/">Дима</a>,
  <a href="/">Лена</a>,
  <a href="/">Витя</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее, каких трудов мне стоило узнать решение моего вопроса. Таки это простой случай? Значит можно и регулярку использовать?

Comment: @gm-111, зависит от того какая разметка может быть.

Comment: @gm-111, кстати, а зачем вообще надо именно так удалять?

Comment: Таким образом удаляю ссылку на корневую категорию, что бы красивее было и понятнее. Например, в перечне с жанрами фильма  будет светится ссылка на корневой каталог (Фильмы), согласитесь, не красиво. Кстати, можно ли как-то проделать тоже самое, но с несколькими классами? Пробовал так: `var toremove = $('.short-genre a:contains("Вася") .short-second a:contains("Вася")');` Но со второго класса не удаляет запятую.

Comment: @gm-111, потому что в условии я просто у первого элемента удаляю следующий. Если в выборке больше одного элемента может быть. то нужно использовать `each` функцию. а хтмл - статичный? или на сервере как-то собирается?

Comment: На сервере собирается, но есть кэширование, сейчас не включено. И кстати, скрипт правильно работает только с первым .short-genre, в остальных оставляет запятые.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31961/discussion-between-grundy-and-gm-111).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = '';
$('.short-genre>a').not(':nth-child(1)').each(function(i, v) {
  if (i > 0) {
    text += ', ';
  }
  text += $(v).text();
});
$('#result').text(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="short-genre">
  <a href="/">Вася</a>,
  <a href="/">Дима</a>,
  <a href="/">Лена</a>,
  <a href="/">Витя</a>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: <div id="result"></div> мне не нужен. Забыл написать в вопросе, что нужно удалить слово **Вася**, а не просто первое слово.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так будет проще и универсальнее:

1. оберните каждую строку в `span`;
2. достаньте первый `span`;
3. удалите его.

Вот такая примерно разметка получится:

```
<div class="short-genre">
    <span><a href="/">Вася</a>, </span>
    <span><a href="/">Дима</a>, </span>
    <span><a href="/">Лена</a>, </span>
    <span><a href="/">Витя</a>, </span>
</div>
```

Вот так можно сделать на jQuery:

```
$('.short-genre>span:first-child').remove();
```

Вот так на vanilla JS:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.short-genre>span'); // можно и такой же селектор как и выше, но не нужно
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Если же не хочется менять разметку удобно вспомнить, как выглядит дерево элементов в DOM и понять как добраться до текстовых узлов. В данной ситуации, для удалении требуемого надо удалить первые три элемента (первый отступ, `a` и текстовый узел с запятой). Например, вот так:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.short-genre');
elem.childNodes[0].remove();
elem.childNodes[0].remove();
elem.childNodes[0].remove();
```

Осторожно, в этом варианте используется современный метод [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), который может быть с легкостью заменен, `.removeChild`.

Comment: Тогда придется перебирать код в движке сайта и вносить изменения.

Comment: @gm-111, проще будет в итоге все равно поменять разметку. Но я обновил ответ.

Comment: Работает. Ну а что если ссылки на Васю не будет, а имен может быть до 20 штук в списке. Можно ли это как-то реализовать? Мне просто надо удалить Васю из списка (если он есть). Если Вася есть, то он будет первым в списке

Comment: @gm-111, элементарно, Ватсон. Делается это добавлением условия `if`, например, вот так `if (/Вася/.test(document.querySelector('.short-genre>span').innerHTML)) {}`

Comment: Опять span используете

Comment: Ну, какая разница, замените на `a`, в чем проблема? Порой надо знать не только как делать, а почему так делать)